# In tensorflow, how do I reset a row of a tensor to zeros?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on recurrent neural network in Tensorflow.
I have a tensor `H` which stores hidden states for a batch of inputs.

Assume that `H` is of size `a*b`. How do I reset rows of `H`, given in a list, to `zeros`?

e.g. if a list is `[1, 2]` I want to reset only those rows of `H` to `zeros`, leaving others intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do this using tensorflow tensors? I am not sure what your exact use case is, but I can't think of reason that you would need to do this. You should be able to pass exactly what you need into a tf.placeholder.

Anyways, to answer your question, you could multiply the tensor that you want to reset by a constant tensor with 1's every where except where you need to reset.

For example:

```
reset_constant = tf.constant([[1,1,1],
                              [1,1,1],
                              [0,0,0], #reset this row
                              [1,1,1]], dtype="float")
tensor_with_reset_row = tf.mul(tensor_to_reset, reset_constant)
```